Android, Java + Goople Map: Straight routes useless. Is it possible to eliminate them?
Video of problem
Straight routes useless. Is it possible to eliminate them? there are straight lines that i wouldn't want.
Input from rest_api it's a simple json in this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S2_xOB9Bj6EqiFwuRNGV5JvrjPjZoQD0/view?usp=sharing
Output: map with markers and **without ANY straight lines. **.
Code :
onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        routePoints = new ArrayList<>();
        noRoutePoints = new ArrayList<>();

        String idTappaSelezionata = MainActivity.idUltimaTappaSelezionata;

        if (idTappaSelezionata != null) {
            mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            StringRequest getPercorsoRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.GET_PERCORSO_URL,
                    response -> {
                        Logger.show("Mappa getData response: " + response + " | Url: " + Config.GET_PERCORSO_URL);

                        try {
                            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray percorsoArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("percorso");

                            if (percorsoArray.length() == 0) {
                                clearRoutes();
                            } else {
                                parseAndDisplayRoute(percorsoArray);
                            }

                            mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // handle exception
                        }
                    },
                    error -> {
                        // handle error
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("user_id", MainActivity.userLoggedId);
                    params.put("id_tappa", idTappaSelezionata);
                    params.put("id_via", MainActivity.idUltimaViaSelezionata);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            SingletonVolley.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(getPercorsoRequest);
        } else {
            showNoRouteDialog();
        }
    }

    private void clearRoutes() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            routePoints.clear();
            noRoutePoints.clear();
        });
    }

    private void parseAndDisplayRoute(JSONArray percorsoArray) throws JSONException {
        for (int i = 0; i < percorsoArray.length(); i++) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String tmpPercorso = percorsoArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
            Percorso newP = gson.fromJson(tmpPercorso, Percorso.class);

            if ("rosso".equals(newP.getColore())) {
                routePoints.add(new LatLng(newP.getLatitude(), newP.getLongitude()));
            } else if ("blu".equals(newP.getColore())) {
                noRoutePoints.add(new LatLng(newP.getLatitude(), newP.getLongitude()));
            }
        }

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (!routePoints.isEmpty()) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(routePoints.get(0), 14));
            }

            if (routePoints.size() > 1 && noRoutePoints.size() > 1) {
                addPolylines();
            }

            addMarker();
            setPolylineClickListener();
        });
    }

    private void addPolylines() {
        List<LatLng> percorso = PolyUtil.simplify(routePoints, 0.0001); // Adjusted tolerance

        PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(percorso)
                .clickable(true)
                .width(10)
                .color(Color.RED);

        googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);

       // List<LatLng> simplifiedNoRoute = PolyUtil.simplify(noRoutePoints, 0.0001); // Adjusted tolerance

        /*PolylineOptions polylineOptionsRosso = new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(simplifiedRoute)
                .clickable(true)
                .width(10)
                .color(Color.RED);

        googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsRosso);

        PolylineOptions polylineOptionsBlu = new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(simplifiedNoRoute)
                .clickable(true)
                .width(10)
                .color(Color.BLUE);

        googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsBlu);*/



        getExperiences(googleMap);
    }

    private void addMarker() {
        LatLng markerMe = routePoints.get(0);
        int customMarkerHeight = 100;
        int customMarkerWidth = 100;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.me);
        Bitmap customMarkerBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap(), customMarkerWidth, customMarkerHeight, false);
        BitmapDescriptor customMarkerMe = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(customMarkerBitmap);

        MarkerOptions markerOp = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(markerMe)
                .icon(customMarkerMe)
                .title("Marker " + getId());

        googleMap.addMarker(markerOp);
    }

    private void setPolylineClickListener() {
        googleMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(polyline -> {
            List<LatLng> path = polyline.getPoints();
            String navigationUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + path.get(path.size() - 1).latitude + "," + path.get(path.size() - 1).longitude;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(navigationUri));
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    private void showNoRouteDialog() {
        mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String message = "Non è stato selezionato nessun percorso. Premere OK per scegliere un percorso.";
        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Le Vie di Francesco");
        dialog.setMessage(message);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).caricaFragment("menu_home", new Vie(), "Vie");
        });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


Where is my bad?

I really need some help... thanks.

Thanks for putting -1 this question. Who made this is very very dumb.

The issue you have is with the data.  It is a collection of segments which, when treated as a single list of points results in those "jumps".
An example "jump" occurs with 'rosso' points at point ids "968" and "15578" (which are consecutive 'rosso' points separated by 'blu' section (more on this ahead):
43.775690,11.439900
43.769571,11.340214

The best solution would be to update your data as different segments (e.g. GPX refers to them as "trkseg"s ) and update your code to support multiple track segments.
Proximity Test
However, assuming the data is not changeable, then a proximity test between points can be applied to detect the "jumps" and build multiple polylines.
To do this, use the SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween() library method.
I simplified your example a bit and modified the treatment of the "red" points and left the "blue" points as the original.  A separate segment list is used to preserve the original lists (since you may need them for other things).
An example distance threshold of 500.0 meters is used - this would be data dependent.
Note: the PolyUtil.simplify is not relevant to your problem and was removed here - but leave it in if desired for other reasons.
private void addPolylines() {

    // "rosso"
    
    List<LatLng> percorso = routePoints;

    List<LatLng> segment = new ArrayList<>();
    LatLng prevPt = percorso.get(0);
    for (LatLng pt : percorso) {
        double d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(prevPt,pt);

        if (d > 500.0) {
            PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                                                       .addAll(segment)
                                                       .clickable(true)
                                                       .width(10)
                                                       .color(Color.RED);

            googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);
            segment.clear();
        }

        segment.add(pt);
        prevPt = pt;
    }
    if (segment.size() > 0) {
        PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                                                   .addAll(segment)
                                                   .clickable(true)
                                                   .width(10)
                                                   .color(Color.RED);

        googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);
        segment.clear();
    }


    // "blu"
    
    percorso = noRoutePoints;

    PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                                               .addAll(percorso)
                                               .clickable(true)
                                               .width(10)
                                               .color(Color.BLUE);

    googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);

}

And result (with good 'rosso' and bad 'blu'):


Color Section Test
Note your data is organized as a series of "rosso" and "blu" segments, as in:
[rosso data]
[blu data]
[rosso data]
[blu data]

So when you reach the end of a "rosso" section, then transition to "blu" and then back to "rosso" the "jump" between consecutive "rosso" points occurs.  These may be your track segments - but as it turns out even within 'blu' you have multiple segments (read on).
So alternately,  you could just build your PolyLines based on these groupings and detect transitions:
private void parseAndDisplayRoute(JSONArray percorsoArray) throws JSONException {
    String lastColor = "";
    List<LatLng> segment = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    LatLng prevPt = new LatLng(0.0,0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < percorsoArray.length(); i++) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String tmpPercorso = percorsoArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
        Percorso newP = gson.fromJson(tmpPercorso, Percorso.class);


        LatLng newPt = new LatLng(newP.getLatitude(), newP.getLongitude());

        if (i == 0) {
            lastColor = newP.getColore();
            segment = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            prevPt = newPt;
        }


        // detect segment transition based on "color" OR distance

        if (!lastColor.equals(newP.getColore())) {
            int color = (lastColor.equals("rosso") ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
            addPolylines(segment, color);
            segment.clear();
        }


        if ("rosso".equals(newP.getColore())) {
            routePoints.add(newPt);
            segment.add(newPt);
        } else if ("blu".equals(newP.getColore())) {
            noRoutePoints.add(newPt);
            segment.add(newPt);
        }

        lastColor = newP.getColore();
        prevPt = newPt;
    }

    if (segment.size() > 0) {
        int color = (lastColor.equals("rosso") ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
        addPolylines(segment, color);
        segment.clear();
    }

    if (!routePoints.isEmpty()) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(routePoints.get(0), 14));
    }

}

private void addPolylines(List<LatLng> pts, int color) {
    PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                                               .addAll(pts)
                                               .clickable(true)
                                               .width(10)
                                               .color(color);

    googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);


}

Result of using just "color" sections - 'blu' still bad since it has multiple segments within it...:

Proximity + Color Section
So finally, combining the two methods (distance + color transition):
private void parseAndDisplayRoute(JSONArray percorsoArray) throws JSONException {
    String lastColor = "";
    List<LatLng> segment = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    LatLng prevPt = new LatLng(0.0,0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < percorsoArray.length(); i++) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String tmpPercorso = percorsoArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
        Percorso newP = gson.fromJson(tmpPercorso, Percorso.class);

        double d = 0.0;

        LatLng newPt = new LatLng(newP.getLatitude(), newP.getLongitude());

        if (i == 0) {
            lastColor = newP.getColore();
            segment = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            prevPt = newPt;
        }


        d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(prevPt,newPt);

        // detect segment transition based on "color" OR distance

        if (!lastColor.equals(newP.getColore()) || d > 500.0) {
            int color = (lastColor.equals("rosso") ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
            addPolylines(segment, color);
            segment.clear();
        }


        if ("rosso".equals(newP.getColore())) {
            routePoints.add(newPt);
            segment.add(newPt);
        } else if ("blu".equals(newP.getColore())) {
            noRoutePoints.add(newPt);
            segment.add(newPt);
        }

        lastColor = newP.getColore();
        prevPt = newPt;
    }

    if (segment.size() > 0) {
        int color = (lastColor.equals("rosso") ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
        addPolylines(segment, color);
        segment.clear();
    }

    if (!routePoints.isEmpty()) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(routePoints.get(0), 14));
    }


    //        addMarker();
    //        setPolylineClickListener();
}

private void addPolylines(List<LatLng> pts, int color) {
    PolylineOptions percorsoPolyline = new PolylineOptions()
                                               .addAll(pts)
                                               .clickable(true)
                                               .width(10)
                                               .color(color);

    googleMap.addPolyline(percorsoPolyline);


}



Notes

In order to test I used the alternate "download" version of your url:
https://drive.usercontent.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1S2_xOB9Bj6EqiFwuRNGV5JvrjPjZoQD0&export=download



Ok when i return to home i will try thanks for any help ❤️

Thank you very much!!!  i will try change color fiesole - pontassieve
